# Инкремент/Декремент

Tags: java

Не могу понять почему в ответе будет единица. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
int x = 0;
System.out.println(++x + --x);
```

Answer (score 7):

`++x` - означает, что к `x` прибавится единица сразу и мы будем пользоваться уже измененным значением; аналогично для `--x`.

1. На первом шаге `x = 0`;
2. После `++x` `x = 1`;
3. После `--x` `x = 0`;
4. `1 + 0 = 1.`

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое, впредь буду внимательнее